# Unable to display x-axis labels on multi-column mysql array in Highcharts

Tags: php, mysql, highcharts, graphing

I have a mysql database containing multiple columns of power values captured over time, with time captured in the first column.  I would like to plot the power values and display the time of day on the x-axis of a Highcharts chart.  I am currently able to display the multiple Power values on the y-axis but I am unable to get the time of day to display on the chart.  Here is the PHP code that partially works:

```
<?php
// Connect to database
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","userid","passwd","power_readings");
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

// Set the variable $rows to the columns Energy_Date and Total_watts
$query = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT Energy_Date,Total_watts FROM combined_readings");
$rows = array();
$rows['name'] = 'Total_watts';
while($tmp = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
  $rows['data'][] = $tmp['Total_watts'];
}

// Set the variable $rows1 to the columns Energy_Date and Power_watts
$query = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT Energy_Date,Power_watts FROM combined_readings");
$rows1 = array();
$rows1['name'] = 'Neurio_watts';
while($tmp = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
    $rows1['data'][] = $tmp['Power_watts'];
}

// Set the variable $rows2 to the columns Energy_Date and Solar_watts
$query = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT Energy_Date,Solar_watts FROM combined_readings");
$rows2 = array();
$rows2['name'] = 'Solar_watts';
while($tmp = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
    $rows2['data'][] = $tmp['Solar_watts'];
}

$result = array();
array_push($result,$rows);
array_push($result,$rows1);
array_push($result,$rows2);

print json_encode($result, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Can someone tell me how to change the code to pass the values from the time of day column properly?

Here is what the chart currently looks like:

[image: Combined Power Values]

When I made changes to the PHP to add the 'Energy_Date' field to the array passed to Highcharts (shown below) it results in a blank chart.

The array consists of fields that look like this (a time stamp followed by a power reading, separated by period:

"2018-02-21 16:56:00.052","2018-02-21 16:59:00.052","2018-02-21 17:02:00.039","2018-02-21 17:05:00.039","2018-02-21 17:08:00.039"

```
<?php
// Connect to database
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","userid","passwd","power_readings");
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

// Set the variable $rows to the columns Energy_Date and Total_watts
$query = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT Energy_Date,Total_watts FROM combined_readings");
$rows = array();
$rows['name'] = 'Total_watts';
while($tmp = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
  $rows['data'][] = $tmp['Energy_Date'].$tmp['Total_watts'];
}

// Set the variable $rows1 to the columns Energy_Date and Power_watts
$query = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT Energy_Date,Power_watts FROM combined_readings");
$rows1 = array();
$rows1['name'] = 'Neurio_watts';
while($tmp = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
    $rows1['data'][] = $tmp['Energy_Date'].$tmp['Power_watts'];
}

// Set the variable $rows2 to the columns Energy_Date and Solar_watts
$query = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT Energy_Date,Solar_watts FROM combined_readings");
$rows2 = array();
$rows2['name'] = 'Solar_watts';
while($tmp = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
    $rows2['data'][] = $tmp['Energy_Date'].$tmp['Solar_watts'];
}

$result = array();
array_push($result,$rows);
array_push($result,$rows1);
array_push($result,$rows2);

print json_encode($result, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

The html receiving this array looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<title>Combined Values Graph</title>
<head>
 <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="180">
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
         $(function () {
             var x_values = [];
             var chart;
             $(document).ready(function() {
                 Highcharts.setOptions({
                     colors: ['#4083e9', '#99ccff', '#00ffff', '#e6e6e6', '#DDDF00', '#64E572', '#FF9655', '#FFF263', '#6AF9C4']
                 });

                 $.getJSON("values.php", function(json) {

                     chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
                         chart: {
                             renderTo: 'mygraph',
                             type : 'spline',
                             borderWidth: 1,
                             zoomType: 'x',
                             panning: true,
                             panKey: 'shift',
                             plotShadow: false,
                             marginTop: 100,
                             height: 500,
                             plotBackgroundImage: 'gradient.jpg'
                         },
                         plotOptions: {
                             series: {
                                 fillOpacity: 1
                             }
                         },
                         plotOptions: {
                             series: {
                                marker: {
                                     enabled: false
                                }
                             }
                         },
                         title: {
                             text: 'Combined Power Readings'

                         },
                         subtitle: {
                             text: 'Total = Neurio + Solar Readings in Watts'

                         },
                         xAxis : {
                             title : {
                                 text : 'Time of Day'
                             }
                         },
                         yAxis: {
                             title: {
                                 text: 'Power (watts)'
                             },
                             plotLines: [{
                                 value: 0,
                                 width: 2,
                                 color: '#ff0000',
                                 zIndex:4,
                                 dashStyle: 'ShortDot'
                             }]
                         },
                         tooltip: {
                             formatter: function() {
                                     return '<b>'+ this.series.name +'</b><br/>'+
                                     this.x +': '+ this.y;
                             }
                         },
                         legend: {
                             layout: 'vertical',
                             align: 'right',
                             verticalAlign: 'top',
                             x: -10,
                             y: 120,
                             borderWidth: 1
                         },
                         plotOptions : {
                             spline : {
                                 marker : {
                                     radius : 0,
                                     lineColor : '#666666',
                                     lineWidth : 0
                                 }
                             }
                         },
                         series: json
                         });
                 });

             });

         });
 </script>
 <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.src.js"></script>
 <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
<div class="container" style="margin-top:20px">
 <div class="col-md-10">
  <div class="panel panel-primary">
    <div class="panel-body">
     <div id ="mygraph"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I have added the console statement to the bottom of the js like so:

```
                 series: json
                 });
                 console.log(json);
         });
```

Here's what is shown in the browser console for PHP version 1 (The version that displays the graphs).

[Browser console 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HEZJy.jpg)

Here's what is shown in the browser console for PHP version 2 (The version that gives a blank chart).

[Browser console 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Btc7p.jpg)

Thanks for your helpful suggestions.  I have changed the while loops to look like this:

```
while($tmp = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
  $rows['data'][] = $tmp['Energy_UTC'];
  $rows['data'][] = $tmp['Total_watts'];
}
```

The output of the PHP now looks like this:

```
[{"name":"Total_watts","data":[1519315164,93,1519315344,354]},{"name":"Neurio_watts","data":[1519315164,76,1519315344,309]},{"name":"Solar_watts","data":[1519315164,17,1519315344,45]}]
```

The data being passed to Highcharts (from the console) now looks like this:

[Browser console 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/16knj.jpg)

The chart is still wrong:  the x-axis is not showing the timestamps and the chart is incorrect.  Can anyone suggest how to change the PHP or html to correct this?

OK, I have updated the while loops to look like this:

```
$query = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT Energy_UTC,Total_watts FROM combined_readings");
$rows = array();
$rows['name'] = 'Total_watts';
while($tmp = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
  $rows['data'][] = [$tmp['Energy_UTC'],$tmp['Total_watts']];
}
```

The PHP output now looks like this:

[{"name":"Total_watts","data":[[1519387869,423],[1519388049,423],[1519388229,332],[1519388410,514],[1519388590,514]...

and the chart is now displaying UTC timestamps for each power value.

Comment: can you add output of `print json_encode($result, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);` this will help us to add answer

Comment: Or add `console.log(json)`  in JS so we can see what is passed to the Highcharts.

Comment: As you can see your dataset is wrong, you have two issues here: 1) x-values are string dates, should be timestamps (number). 2) Your updated data contains only x-values, no y-values. Data should look like this `data: [ [1519280220000, 233], [ ..., ... ], [ ..., ... ] ]`

Comment: The updated data actually consists of x and y values with a dot separating them:  "2018-02-22 07:17:00.0233".  I can change the string date to a UTC timestamp, but I have not been able to format the while statement to insert a comma like you have suggested.  Can you suggest how the while statement should be changed to fix this?

Comment: @tgraf2 Okay.  Don't go away.  Let's fix this sucker too.  It is a lot to read, but I can help you through it.  Do you know what output you are trying to achieve to make HighCharts work as intended, or are you unsure of what the `data` should look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are writing a large block of code with many duplicated components.  I've taken the time to DRY your method.  It is best practice to minimize calls to the database, so I've managed to combine your queries into one simple select.

Theoretically, you will only need to modify `$colnames_labels` to modify your HighChart.  I have written inline comments to help you to understand what my snippet does.  I have written some basic error checks to help you to debug if anything fails.

Code: (untested)

```
$colnames_labels=[
    'Total_watts'=>'Total_watts',
    'Power_watts'=>'Neurio_watts',
    'Solar_watts'=>'Solar_watts'
];

$select_clause_ext='';                            // declare as empty string to allow concatenation
foreach($colnames_labels as $colname=>$label){
    $data[]=['name'=>$label];                     // pre-populate final array with name values
    // generates: [0=>['name'=>'Total_watts'],1=>['name'=>'Neurio_watts'],2=>['Solar_watts']]
    $select_clause_ext.=",$colname";
    // generates: ",Total_watts,Power_watts,Solar_watts"
}

$subarray_indexes=array_flip(array_keys($colnames_label));  // this will route resultset data to the correct subarray
// generates: ['Total_watts'=>0,'Power_watts'=>1,'Solar_watts'=>2]

if(!$result=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(Energy_Date) AS Stamp{$select_clause_ext} FROM combined_readings ORDER BY Energy_Date")){
    $data=[['name'=>'Syntax Error (query error)','data'=>[0,0]];  // overwrite data with error message & maintain expected format
}elseif(!mysqli_num_rows($result)){
    $data=[['name'=>'Logic Error (no rows)','data'=>[0,0]];
}else{
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
        foreach($subarray_indexes as $i=>$col){
            $data[$i]['data'][]=[$row['Stamp'],$row[$col]];  // store [stamp,watts] data in appropriate subarrays
        }
    }
}

echo json_encode($data,JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);  // Convert to json (while encoding numeric strings as numbers) and print to screen
```

Comment: Thanks for your effort and suggestions mickmackusa.  My code is now 90% correct.  Before I replace it I would like to fine tune it.